# Only arrays and iterables are allowed - Unable to debug/understand the problem

Tags: angular, typescript

I have started using angular and apologies for posting this issue again. I have referred many posts related to the error but unable to debug/resolve the below error. Please can anyone let me know what is wrong in my code.

Using below html code, I can display the values in UI on page load and submit data.

```
<div class="row Result" *ngFor="let result of projectSet; let i = index" > // Error on this line
  <div class="col-md-2">{{result.id}}</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">{{result.name}}</div>
</div>
<div>
   <button (click)="submit(this.addDataForm)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

After submit operation completes, I see below error in console which I am unable to resolve.
Error:

```
Error trying to diff 'fghfghgf'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:19139)
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3373)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22102)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MyComponent.html:21)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
```

This is the below code which pulls the **projectSet** information.

```
component.ts code:
    this.addProjectService.getProjects().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.projectSet = response;
        this.projectSet = this.projectSet.filter(obj => obj.id === this.projectID);
        this.sharingservice.setSettings(this.projectSet)
      },
      error => {
        this.projectSet = this.sharingservice.getUserSettings()
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Please do a `console.log(response)` inside the subscription and post it's output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are tying to loop and object and not an array.

```
{
'a': [{'name':'Jan','age':20}],
'b': [{'name':'Feb','age':51}]
}
```

If your object is of similar structure then do,

```
<div *ngFor="let result of Object.keys(projectSet); let i = index">
   <div class="col-md-2">{{key}} - {{projectSet[key].name}}</div>
</div>
```